# Wrong parameters in POST request

Tags: android, ios, rest, post

I am new in iOS.

I make request with 2 key-value parameters:

```
NSString* params = @"sid=d2a8b790364944ef870ed94c1e4fdea3 & phone=+380503424248";
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gps.privatbank.ua/auth/check"];

[request setURL:url];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil];

NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;

NSString *result = [results valueForKey:@"result"];

if([result isEqualToString:@"error"]){
    authorizationViewController = [AuthorizationViewController new];
    [authorizationViewController openEnterPhone:self];
}
```

But server always returns response {"result":"error"}

When I pass this data throw Postman  - returns "success"

[image]

The same request but in Android application looks like:

```
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://gps.privatbank.ua/auth/check");

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sid", PreferenceController.getSsid(context)));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("phone_number","")));

postMethod.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();

String response = getInstance().execute(postMethod, res);
```

... and returns "success".

Wich parameter I have missed?

**UPD:**

I have understood where problem is. Postman convert '+' symbol (in phone number) into '%2B', but my POST request doesn't do this. 
So which parameter I must set to correct this?

Comment: Try to assign your `NSError` when creating `jsonData` and see why is failing first. The proceed down the line

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`NSString* params = @"sid=d2a8b790364944ef870ed94c1e4fdea3&&phone=+380503424248";`

I hope this helps , 
Cheers.

Comment: No. [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:nil] returns nil

Answer (score 0):

Using the following code I was able to get response from this server:

```
NSString* params = @"sid=d2a8b790364944ef870ed94c1e4fdea3&phone=+380503424248";
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gps.privatbank.ua/auth/check"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];

    [request setURL:url];

    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
    request.HTTPBody = [params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSError *error;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

    if(error)NSLog(@"ERROR:%@",error);

    NSDictionary *results = jsonData ? [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error] : nil;
    NSString *result = error ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ERROR-->%@",error.localizedDescription] : results;

    NSLog(@"RESULT:%@",result);
```

`NSLog` for `RESULT:{
    result = error;
}`

First thing I've noticed was you have a blank space in your `params` string before and after `&` sign of your parameters. Remove the blank space and should work no problem.

**UPD.**
Escape your strings before you POST them with the method bellow.

```
-(NSString*)escapeString:(NSString*)string
{

 NSString *escapedString = (NSString*)CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL,(__bridge CFStringRef)string, NULL, CFSTR("!*();:@&=+$./?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8));

 return escapedString;

}
```

Comment: Very strange. I've copy-pasted your code and got wrong response. What response did you get?

Comment: Another thing that isn't in your code in this post is where you initialize your `request` object. Did you have it like this `NSMutableURLRequest *request;` or like this `NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]init];?`

Comment: I think you're not initializing your `NSMutableURLRequest` properly and that's why your `NSData` is alway `nil`

Comment: NSData isn't nil. It = {"result":"error"}. But must be {"result":"success"} - like in POSTMAN request emulator.

Comment: It looks like it doesn't like the encoding for some reason. Do you have access to servers log files or what the server receives from your application?

Comment: It looks like problem in '+' symbol. I added this in topic.